# How to set up a meteor server on https connection?

Tags: ssl, meteor, https

I have a local meteor server running on port 3000.Then I want add the SSL Certificate to my project.I have generate the SSL files, what should I do the next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy the app using [Meteor Up](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) which have built in [SSL support](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up#ssl-support).

Or use common web server like Nginx or Apache, setup SSL and reverse proxy back to meteor app.

Example: Nginx configuration

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name www.example.com;
  rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl ;
  server_name www.example.com;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/ssl.key;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  }

}
```

Comment: I use the docker to deploy my meteor project, so I probably not quite fit the meteor up.I want to choose the second way but I haven't the base knowledge of 'reverse proxy'.So I have some questions below:(1)If I use the reverse proxy . Should I do anything else with the meteor project? (2)Is the 'reverse proxy' method meaning that the proxy wrap the meteor and the proxy will be in full charge of the SSL Certificate process?

Comment: (1) You don't have to configure anything to Meteor. (2) Right. I suggest you configure nginx in docker. Nginx will receive request from client, do ssl termination and forward the request to Meteor.

Comment: Thak u very much! I will have a try ~